# ESXi Wake on LAN single host

Tags: vmware-esxi, wake-on-lan

I have a single esxi host I want to use WOL (wake on lan) to remotely power on. I do not have a vcenter server setup. Everything i've read says you have to have a Vcenter server and Vmotion setup to utilize wake on lan. Is this correct or can I send WOL packets to a single host and have it power on? If so how can I do this?

---

Thanks for your response.

I'm currently building a home lab and trying to decide if I want to spend the extra money on a super micro board that has IPMI natively. The problem with that is those board support only ECC Ram so that starts driving cost up. This is only a home lab so i don't need ECC. I would rather buy a 50-90 mother board, 32gb cheap ram, and a intel 3.3 quad core processor. I want to have the ability to power the lab on remotely when i'm traveling. I have a VPN setup to my house so I can accomplish this. I don't want the server running 24/7. So i'm asking the question to determine if I can go with the cheaper solution using WOL vs paying more for a IPMI solution.

This is the IPMI solution but its really expensive.

Supermicro Motherboard uATX DDR3 1600 LGA 1150 MBD-X10SLH-F-O
Intel Xeon E3-1230V3 Haswell, 3.3GHz, 8MB L3 Cache LGA 1150, 80W Quad-Core Server Processor
Crucial 32GB Kit (8GBx4) DDR3L 1600MT/s (PC3-12800) DR x8 ECC UDIMM

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this?

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution for vSphere and host power management is linked to the [Distributed Power Management](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features/drs-dpm) feature available at the highest tier of vSphere Enterprise Plus licensing.

You can place hosts in Standby/Sleep and wake via WOL and/or IPMI/ILO.

**But this cool stuff all requires vCenter.**

[image]

[image]

I believe you can send [generic Wake-on-LAN packets to an ESXi host](http://www.ntpro.nl/blog/archives/1487-Using-Wake-on-LAN-WOL-to-power-on-your-ESX-hosts.html) if your NIC is configured for it. Obviously, this would need to be sent from another, non-virtualized system...

But why go through the trouble? If you have IPMI or ILO/DRAC or *any* [out-of-band management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) solution, wouldn't that be a better idea?

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I tested sending generic Wake-on-LAN packets, did not work with the E1000 network card, had to switch to VMXNET3 and succeeded.
Also found that info in the official vSphere documentation: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50%2FGUID-35CD5E60-6FFA-47CE-A5CF-78B6D6B42CB8.html